# d3.scaleTime renders only NaN

Tags: d3.js, angular11

I am drawing an x-axis based timeline for objects with the property **startDateTime:Date**. No matter what I inject into the d3.timeScale (e.g.Date.now())  whether in the code or inside a console.log it always returns NaN. d3.extent, d3.min and d3.max recognize and return the correct min and max dates from the same source.

I installed d3 and d3@types with npm. d3 v6.

The axes render with their labels, but the rect objects render on top of one another like this:

```
<rect class="rect" x="NaN" height="10" width="10" style="fill: blue; opacity: 0.5;"></rect>
```

In the populate() function, if I don't wrap the d.startDateTime in a new Date() the rect is rendered like this:

```
<rect class="rect" height="10" width="10" style="fill: blue; opacity: 0.5;"></rect>
```

I don't know if the missing y value is related to the x value not being calculated correctly.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3/index';

buildSvg():void{
    this.host.html('');
    this.svg = this.host.append('svg')
      .attr("width",'100%')
      .attr("height",'200')
      .style("background-color",'#e2e2ec')
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left +','+ this.margin.top + ')');
    var timeDomain = d3.extent(this.timeData, t => t.startDateTime);
    this.xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(timeDomain)
      .range([0,1800]);
    this.yScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain([this.locations])
      .range([this.height,0]);
  }


 populate(){
    this.svg.selectAll('.rect')
      .data(this.timeData)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class','rect')
      .attr('x',d => this.xScale(new Date(d.startDateTime)))
      .attr('y',d=> this.yScale(d.location))
      .attr('height',10)
      .attr('width',10)
      .style('fill', 'blue')
      .style('opacity',0.5)

  }

drawXAxis(){
    this.xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.xScale)
      .ticks(5)
      .tickPadding(15);
    this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class','x axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0, '+ this.height +')')
      .call(this.xAxis)
      .append('text')
      .attr('class','label')
      .attr('x', this.width)
      .attr('y',-6)
      .style('text-anchor', 'end')
      .style('fill', 'grey')
      .text('Date ')
 }
```

Comment: What do you get when you console log timeDomain ?

Comment: What happens if you change your line for rect to .attr(„x“, d => this.xScale(d.Start.DateTime))

Comment: The domain probably currently doesn’t expect dates (in a Date format

Comment: timeDomain returns this array: ["2017-04-13T08:00", "2017-09-07T17:00"]

Comment: .attr('x',d => this.xScale(d.startDateTime)) returns a <rect> with no x value at all-->the second example above and the domain is being passed a Date object from a json source.

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal working example ?

Comment: From your comment it looks like you don’t initialize the domain with dates. The array of timeDomain returns an array of two strings not two dates.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the missing piece which is not shown in the code. My guess is you read a file of dates and by default store it as string. You may just need to convert the data to Dates then the domain is set wir th actual Dates and your x Attribute (without the Date conversion should do it (since u converted earlier

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks for asking the right questions:**

Parse a date string like this: 2017-04-13T11:00 with this function

```
    parseDate(date):number{
      return Date.parse(date.toString());
    }
```

returns a number which is what the d3.scaleTime is looking for. While the d3.extent function returns valid ISO strings, you must do the same for those values. The final d3.scaleTime function:

```
    this.minDate = d3.min(this.timeData, t => t.startDateTime);
    this.maxDate = d3.max(this.timeData, t => t.startDateTime);

 var testTimeScale=  d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([this.parseDate(this.minDate),this.parseDate(this.maxDate)])
      .range([100,1200]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was banging my head for hours. In my case timeScale was always empty.
You can also use this.minData.getTime() to achive the same without the extra function.